# Node - Search for dependancy recursively

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to search recursively and find if I'm using a certain Node module. Is this possible?

Comment: You can just open package-lock.json and search in there.

Comment: Sometimes there may be a package, which was not added to the main project's dependencies, but by some other package or its dependencies (or their dependencies and so on) might be using. File search may help, but I felt like using something more just to be sure. The answer by @justin.m.chase helped with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean not at runtime you can do:

```
npm ls <module name to search for>
```

For example:

```
$ npm ls async
/Users/justin/code/example
├─┬ aws-cdk@0.19.0
│ └─┬ archiver@2.1.1
│   └── async@2.1.4  deduped
├─┬ mongooster@6.0.2
│ └─┬ mongoose@5.3.5
│   └── async@2.6.1
└─┬ sqs-consumer@3.8.0
  └── async@2.1.4
```

At runtime you can use `require.resolve`

```
> require.resolve('async')
'/Users/justin/code/example/node_modules/async/dist/async.js'
```

Or you can require the module then look in the cache to get details about the module, including its parent chain.

```
> require.cache[require.resolve('async')]
Module {
  id: '/Users/justin/code/example/node_modules/async/dist/async.js',
  exports: { ... },
  parent: Module { ... },
  filename: '/Users/justin/code/example/node_modules/async/dist/async.js',
  loaded: true,
  children: [],
  paths: [ ... ]
}
```